# How can I access the ApplicationContext from within a JAX-WS web service?

Tags: java, web-services, spring, jax-ws

Similar to [How can I access the ServletContext from within a JAX-WS web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261348/how-can-i-access-the-servletcontext-from-within-a-jax-ws-web-service), is there a way to access applicationContext, easier than this?

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;

import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils;

@WebService
public class MyWebService {
    // boilerplate code begins :(

    @Resource
    private WebServiceContext context;
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = null;

    /**
     * @return
     * @throws IllegalStateException
     */
    private WebApplicationContext getWebApplicationContext()
            throws IllegalStateException {
        if (webApplicationContext != null)
            return webApplicationContext;
        ServletContext servletContext =
                (ServletContext) context.getMessageContext().get(
                        MessageContext.SERVLET_CONTEXT);
        webApplicationContext =
                WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
        return webApplicationContext;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the web service should have to know about web or servlet contexts or its application context.  I don't see why it should have to know any of that.  Shouldn't it be far more passive?  Inject what it needs and let it do its work.  The service interactions with a client should be based on a contract defined up front.  If it has to get unknown values from a context of some kind, how will clients know what needs to be set or how to set it?

I'd go further and say that a web service should be a wrapper for a Spring service interface.  It's just one more choice among all the possible ways to expose it.  Your web service should do little more than marshal and unmarshal the XML request/response objects and collaborate with Spring services.

Comment: Well, then how can I collaborate with Spring services, if I cannot say: appContext.getBean('myBean')?

Comment: Inject it in via setter or constructor.  Dependency injection means "don't call us; we'll call you."  Your objects don't have to have the app context to get what they need.

Comment: You cannot. If I test my web service under glassfish, a new webservice is created, and it is not configured :-o That was a one-day-long debugging to get this knowledge :(

Comment: I'm writing Spring web services that I'm deploying under WebLogic, and I don't have to supply the application context.  They're working fine for me - SOAP UI clients have no problems working with them.  I think you're doing something else wrong.

Comment: So, you autowired the required beans in your Service class?

Comment: Boy, a simple example of what you mean would be really helpful.

Answer (score 8):

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport;


@WebService( 
    endpointInterface = "Bla", 
    targetNamespace = "http://bla/v001", 
    wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/bla.wsdl",    
    serviceName = "BlaService",
    portName = "BlaPort")
public class BlaWs extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport implements BlaPort {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("dao") 
  private Dao dao;
  ...
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for pointing me in the direction of `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport`.  I had been struggling with getting Glassfish to relinquish its management of JAX-WS and letting Spring to it.  This is a much easier solution and lets Spring stay focused on the things that it is good at.

Comment: I've been trying to get the solution to work but SpringBeanAutowiringSupport just doesn't seem to have an effect on my web service.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869014/web-service-exposed-by-extending-springbeanautowiringsupport-is-failing-to-injec

Answer (score 1):

Make your web service bean extend a spring bean.

like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199047/something-like-ejb-wiring-in-spring-for-non-ejbs)

Answer (score 0):

I would install a Filter that saves ServletContext before chaining in a ThreadLocal

Answer (score 0):

According to the JavaDoc for the SpringBeanAutowiringSupport class, see:
http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/support/SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.html

Read the NOTE: at the end of the javadoc.

The original question, may in fact, be the way that this should be implemented.