# web service exposed by extending SpringBeanAutowiringSupport is failing to inject @Autowired dependencies

Tags: spring

My web service exposed by extending SpringBeanAutowiringSupport is failing to inject @Autowired dependencies.

Web service deploys fine and I'm able to invoke the @WebMethod but I'm getting a NullPointerException due to the failed injection.

I put `System.out.println("Consructing XmlContactMapper...");` in the constructor of XmlContactMapper (one of my dependencies with @Autowired).  When I deploy the web service I see the debug line so I know the constructor is being invoked.  But for some reason an instance of XmlContactMapper isn't being injected into my ContactServiceImpl xmlMapper property.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Using...

- Spring 3.0.5.RELEASE
- GlassFish 3.1
- jaxws-rt 2.1.4

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">

    <display-name>contact-sib</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>           
            classpath:/config/bean-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JaxWsEndpoint</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JaxWsEndpoint</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/contact</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

### sun-jaxws.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime"
           version="2.0">

  <endpoint name="ContactService" 
            implementation="com.bb.sc.sib.contact.ContactServiceImpl" 
            url-pattern="/services/contact"/>

</endpoints>
```

### bean-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context ="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:p = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.bb.sc.sib.contact"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="xmlMapper" class="com.bb.sc.sib.contact.XmlContactMapper"/>

</beans>
```

### web service

```
@WebService (endpointInterface="com.bb.sc.sei.contact.ContactService", serviceName="JaxWsContactService")
public class ContactServiceImpl extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport implements ContactService {
    @Autowired
    private ContactComponent contactComponent;
    @Autowired
    private MapperFacade xmlMapper;
```

### Logging

```
INFO: 10:56:40.073 [admin-thread-pool-4848(419)] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport - Current WebApplicationContext is not available for processing of ContactServiceImpl: Make sure this class gets constructed in a Spring web application. Proceeding without injection.
```

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that you could actually extend SpringBeanAutowiringSupport and have fields wired in - can I recommend turning on DEBUG level and seeing what Spring prints out here, that could provide a good direction on what could be going wrong

Comment: Sounds like your webservice class `ContactServiceImpl` is getting instantiated before the Spring container gets loaded up.

Comment: When I deploy the web service I do see the debug lines in my ContactServiceImpl first.  So the issue does seem related to timing.

Comment: Is ContactServiceImpl bean defined in your spring context?

Comment: ContactServiceImpl is not defined in my spring context (bean-config).  I did try defining it there and the injection works fine but that instance isn't what's being invoked from the /services/contact servlet URL.  The prob seems to be that my endpoint is initialized before my spring context.  So SpringBeanAutowringSupport has no effect.  I've updated my post to include a debug logging that mentions this.

Comment: is there anyone out there that's gotten this to work on GlassFish?  https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9786?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel

Comment: It missed WSServletContextListener may be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Biji suggested, I think this could be a load-order issue between your ContactServiceImpl vs. ContactComponent

Typically, the reason you would need to extend SpringBeanAutowiringSupport is that you have some bean that's instantiated outside of your Spring container, but you want it to resolve it's dependencies via Spring.

Since you're using Glassfish + Metro, you might take a look at the Metro Spring integration support:
http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/spring/

Using this route, the **com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet** should take care of proper loading order with respect to your Spring context.

Comment: Replacing WSServlet with WSSpringServlet worked.  I got rid of the SpringBeanAutowiringSupport extention and sun-jaxws.xml.  I configured a ContactServiceImpl bean like usual in bean-congif.xml.  Then I wired that bean to the jaxws servlet and exposed the service by following <ws:service> and <wss:binding> examples.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The order of the listeners is important. The `ContextLoaderListener` must be defined before the `WSServletContextListener`.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:wsContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Zeemee stated already, the order of the listener definition is crucial. Additionally I had to add `<absolute-ordering/>` in `web.xml`, because Tomcat 8.0.26 gave no respect to the order by itself.