# Different ways of accessing configuration parameters from a JAX-WS service

Tags: configuration, parameters, jax-ws

As far as I know I can access the web.xml `<context-param>`s by making my class implement `ServletContextListener` and use the `ServletContext.getInitParam(String)` to read them, but it´s cumbersome as only one instance of the class will receive the `contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)` call, so I need to make the `ServletContext` an static member of the class.

What other ways exist of setting conf params at deployment time and what are the recommended ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems that the best way of actually getting the ServletContext is via the `MessageContext` as described in [How can I access the ServletContext from within a JAX-WS web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261348/how-can-i-access-the-servletcontext-from-within-a-jax-ws-web-service)