# Web service servlet context is null

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, soap

I am developing a stand alone web service, which doesn't need to be running inside a web container.

It looks very similar to this:

http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ramapulavarthi/archive/2006/06/maintaining_ses.html

I also found the following:

[How can I access the ServletContext from within a JAX-WS web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261348/how-can-i-access-the-servletcontext-from-within-a-jax-ws-web-service)

I enabled the session management from the client with this:

```
((BindingProvider) webInterface).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY, true);
```

on the server side, I was able to get the message context:

```
MessageContext mc = wsContext.getMessageContext();
```

But when I trying to get:

```
Object c = mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);
```

The object `c` is always `null`.